# Get Saleable product options for configurable product

Tags: magento, product

How do I get the saleable product attributes (attribute values of associated simple products that are enabled, have stock, ...) for a given configurable product?

Comment: limex, are you want options values or attribute label

Comment: @AmitBera: I need the attrite structur. The same as I get with getConfigurableAttributes in Marius's answer. But only those that are sellable.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the valid simple products associated to a configurable one like this:

```
$products = array();
$allProducts = $mainProduct->getTypeInstance(true)
    ->getUsedProducts(null, $mainProduct);
foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
    if ($product->isSaleable()) {
        $products[] = $product;
    }
}
```

and you can get the configurable attributes for the configurable product like this:

```
$attributes = $mainProduct->getTypeInstance(true)
        ->getConfigurableAttributes($mainProduct);
```

in both cases `$mainProduct` is the configurable product instance.

Now you can put them all together as you wish. I would have done it but your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: tnkx for your answer. I found out that getConfigurableAttributes doesn't care if the corresponding product is enabled and on stock. It gives all of them. 
So I will try your first code snippet and add the code for getting the attributes of the simple products. tnx so far